# Simply JavaScript code in a loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

This script loops through a number 1-20. I discovered that the  tags  are repeated 20 times.

```
<?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 20; $i++) { ?>
    <button id="btn-<?php echo $i;?>">Button<?php echo $i;?></button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#btn-<?php echo $i;?>').clck(function() {
            alert("you clicked button <?php echo $i;?>");
        }); 
<?php } ?>
```

I want to do the `$('#btn-<?php echo $i;?>').clck(function() {....` once outside the loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you've written here is an anti-pattern. Use a common class on all the elements in the loop and attach a single event handler to that class. For example:

```
<?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 20; $i++) { ?>
    <button class="foo" data-id="btn-<?php echo $i;?>">Button<?php echo $i;?></button>
<?php } ?>
```

```js
// in an external .js file far, far away
$('.foo').click(function() {
    console.log("You clicked button " + $(this).data('id'));
});
```

---

Here's a runnable code snippet. Note **PHP only has to generate the HTML** below. The JavaScript will then attach the `click` event handler to each button.

```js
$('.foo').click(function() {
  console.log("You clicked button " + $(this).data('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="foo" data-id="1">Button 1</button>
<button class="foo" data-id="2">Button 2</button>
<button class="foo" data-id="3">Button 3</button>
<button class="foo" data-id="4">Button 4</button>
```

Comment: I was in the middle of answering something similar but didn't want to effectively duplicate your answer. I included a runnable code snippet to give the OP a tangible result. Feel free to edit/remove it if you find it confusing.